# c# список xml тегов

Tags: c#, linq2xml

Есть xml

```
   <tag>
    <tag1>    </tag1>
    <tag2>    </tag2>
    <root>
    <ttt><t1></t1><t2></t2></ttt>
    <ttt><t1></t1><t2></t2><t3></t3></ttt>
    <ttt><t1></t1></ttt>
    </root>
   </tag>
```

Перебираю названия xml тегов таким кодом:

```
foreach (var x in doc.Descendants())
   listBox1.Items.Add(x.Name);
```

Теги собираются по всему документу и дубли не дубли т.е. и одинаковые по много раз.
Как бы дополнить код, чтобы можно было указать root тег и собрать уникальные?

На выходе нужно:
t1
t2
t3
и другие теги t4, t5 и т.д. если они есть в корневом TTT теге документа

Comment: Вам нужны только те тэги, которые находятся внутри `<ttt>`?

Comment: Да, внутри TTT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо выборки всех тэгов:

```
doc.Descendants()
```

Нужно выбрать тэги, находящиеся внутри `<ttt>`, и вывести только уникальные:

```
doc.Descendants() // выбираем все тэги
    .Where(x => x.Name == "ttt") // выбираем среди них тэги ttt
    .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants()) // выбираем тэги внутри ttt
    .Select(x => x.Name).Distinct() // выбираем уникальные имена
```

Итого:

```
var tagNames = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "ttt")
    .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants())
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .Distinct();

// опционально можно отсортировать
// tagNames = tagNames.OrderBy(x => x.LocalName);

foreach (var x in tagNames)
   listBox1.Items.Add(x);
```